# Single responsibility principle in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I have a MVC project with following pattern

`View <-> Controller <-> Service <-> Repository/Entities <-> Database`

For example, if I have 2 tables (Customer and Order) in my Database, then I have 2 classes in my Repository layer (this class map 1:1 with my database table because I'm using EF Code First) :

```
public class Customer
{
     [Key]
     public int CustomerID { get; set; }
     public int Name { get; set; }
     //rest of columns here
}

public class Order
{
     [Key]
     public int OrderId { get; set; }
     //rest of columns here
}
```

Then I have services :

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
     void AddNewCustomer(Customer obj);
     void GetCustomerOrders(Customer obj);
     //rest of methods here
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
     void GetOrderById(int id);
     void GetCustomerOrders(Customer obj);
     //rest of methods here
}
```

you probably notice that I have `GetCustomerOrders`.

My question :

1. Without breaking Single responsibility principle rule, where do I put `GetCustomerOrders`? In `CustomerService`, `OrderService`, or both?
2. Did I break the Single responsibility principle rule by having more than one service in my controller? For example :

   ```
    public class TransactionController : Controller
    {
         //more than 1 service inside this class
         private ICustomerService _customerService;
         private IOrderService _orderService;

         public ProjectController()
         {
             this._customerService = new CustomerService();
             this._orderService = new OrderService();
         }

         public ProjectController(CustomerService customerService, OrderService orderService)
         {
             this._customerService = customerService;
             this._orderService = orderService;
         }

         public ActionResult Index()
         {
              Return View();
         }

         public ActionResult CreateCustomer()
         {
              //rest of code here
         }

         public ActionResult CreateOrder()
         {
              //rest of code here
         }
    }
   ```
3. I have bunch of controller with bloated Action method, for example my `ProductController` have :

   ```
    Index
    Add
    Edit
    Delete
    Priority
    AddPriority
    EditPriority
    DeletePriority
   ```

   If the controller were split

   ```
    ProductController
          Index
          Add
          Edit
          Delete
    ProductPriorityController
          Index
          Add
          Edit
          Delete
   ```

   I see that the template project from Microsoft doesn't have more than one CRUD operation inside their Controller (towards bottom example). Is it a bad design if I have more than one CRUD operation inside my controller (top example)? I was thinking of splitting my Controller but I don't want it to bite my ass later for having to maintain 50 controllers.

Any help will be appreciated and apologize for bad english.

Comment: No apologies needed for "english" - you're doing great :) IMHO, as far as _templates_ are concerned, I would treat them as "basic crud ops" (to get you going) and if all your `Actions` concern `Product` then that is the controller's (single) responsibility. I would even imagine further separation from "user" vs "admin" contexts of a real world application for managing `Products` etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. I will put it in customerService because it depends on the **customer** you pass to the function.
2. I think that the maximum services for controller is about ~3/4 services in one controller. So in your case i think this is good.
3. The controller doesn't need to implement your business logic. They only should take data and post them to the right place. I think you should create a manager / service / class that will handle the business logic. About your CRUD operations, It should be all in one controller (get/post and etc).

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest making a `CustomerOrdersController`.
2. No, that's fine. In fact, you are dividing the different responsibilities over separate services, which is very "single responsibility".
3. I'd say keep them separate if they do separate things. Maintaining a number of controllers is easy if you know which controller is responsible for what.

Answer (score 0):

1- You don't always need to go through a service to access the repository in the controller.

You can embrace an [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) for example where instead a 3 layers architecture. Personally I think important the concept of accessing layers in the right way, but adding a indirection level just to call a repository with no logic inside the service, makes me question the value of the service, because in that case, what is the service that the service is providing?
Since your repository knows the domain, you can return domain objects.

What about [commands and queries](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)?

You can read a little bit more and make your one of all this your preference or maybe adapt an idea. Just keep the idea of separation of concerns always in mind, you are on the good way.

About questions 2 and 3 I agree with @Rik, but I will paste his answer just to make my answer complete (credit on him)

2- No, that's fine. In fact, you're are dividing the different responsibilities over separate services, which is very "single responsibility"

3- I'd say keep them separate if they do separate things. Maintaining a number of controllers is easy if you know which controller is responsible for what.